# override function in trait

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following trait

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def overrideMe(other:Foo[T]) : Int
}
```

I would like to be able to do

```
class Bar extends Foo[Int] {
   override  def overrideMe(other:Bar) : Int = other.BarFn
}
```

but it does not compile. The reason is that I would like overrideMe to be able to use functionality of the subtype. I could do something like

```
class Bar extends Foo[Int] {
   override  def overrideMe(other:Foo[Int]) : Int = {
      other.asInstanceOf[Bar].BarFn
}
```

but that doesn't look very nice.

Is it possible to say in the trait that the virtual funcation can be overridden with a subtype?

***edit***
@agilesteel That almost works, but I run into trouble if I have a function in another class relying only on the trait Foo

```
class Test[T] {
    def callOverrideMe(a : Foo[T], b : Foo[T] ) : Int = a.overrideMe(b)
}
```

I get a compile error: type mismatch; found b.type (with underlying type foo.Foo[T]) required a.SubType

Comment: I don't think you can do that in Scala. Even in Java you can't do that because then you are really change the signature of `Foo.overrideMe` which would break the contract. And this why you are doing `other.asInstanceOf[Bar]` because other is not guaranteed to be Bar.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is an algorithm relying on a trait and then have some functions implemented in the sub types. Are there any other good design pattern for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Test[T] {
    def callOverrideMe(a : Foo[T], b : Foo[T] ) : Int = a.overrideMe(b)
}
```

Of course, you can't get it to work with this signature. Just consider

```
class Baz extends Foo[Int] {...}

new Test[Int].callOverrideMe(new Bar, new Baz)
```

This should be the same as `new Bar.overrideMe(new Baz)`, but you don't want it to compile!

You can use the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for this:

```
trait Foo[T, Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]] {
  def overrideMe(other:Sub) : Int
}

class Bar extends Foo[Int, Bar] {
   override def overrideMe(other:Bar) : Int = other.BarFn
}

class Test[T] {
    def callOverrideMe[Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]](a : Sub, b : Sub) : Int = a.overrideMe(b)
}
```

> What I am trying to accomplish is an algorithm relying on a trait and then have some functions implemented in the sub types. Are there any other good design pattern for this?

Check out Scalaz type classes. E.g. https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Equal.scala

Comment: Question: "The `T` in `Test[T]` differs from the `T` in `callOverrideMe[Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]]` so it would probably be better to let the _class_ define the generic constraint instead of the _method_ as follows `Test[Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]]`, wouldn't it?"

Comment: @agilesteel: "The `T` in `Test[T]` differs from the `T` in `callOverrideMe[Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]]`" Not with this definition. "`Test[Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]]`" It would actually be `Test[T, Sub <: Foo[T, Sub]]`, but yes, it makes a bit more sense (though I'd prefer to have both `T` and `Sub` defined on method).

Answer (score 7):

```
trait Foo[T] {
  type TheSubType <: Foo[T]
  def overrideMe(other: TheSubType) : Int
}

class Bar extends Foo[Int] {
   type TheSubType = Bar
   override def overrideMe(other: Bar) : Int = other.barFn
   def barFn = 10
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the second part of your question, agilesteel's solution can work with a type refinement,

```
trait Foo[T] {
  type R <: Foo[T]
  def overrideMe(other: R) : Int
}

class Bar extends Foo[Int] {
  type R = Bar
  override def overrideMe(other: Bar) : Int = other.barFn
  def barFn = 10
}

def callOverrideMe[T, R0 <: Foo[T]{type R = R0}](a : R0, b : R0) : Int = {
  a.overrideMe(b)
}
```

There might be difficulty inferring type `T` in `callOverrideMe`. A way to improve type inference is to make `R` higher kinded---i.e., give it its own type parameter `T`.

This solution is basically equivalent to Alexey Romanov's, and demonstrates how abstract types can be surfaced as type parameters.